# Unable to deploy to elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm really struggling with my django project deployment. I'm attempting to deploy to elastic beanstalk using this guide.
 https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/elastic_beanstalk_django.md

Within Elastic Beanstalk, the health of my severe is 'severe' and I'm getting the following errors:

Issue 1

```
[Sun Apr 21 06:15:42.463620 2019] [:error] [pid 28281] [client 172.31.24.0:64074] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
```

When I try to run 'eb deploy', I get the following error:

Issue 2

```
Collecting pywin32==223 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 19))     
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==223 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 19)) (from versions: )   
No matching distribution found for pywin32==223 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 19)) 
I'm not sure if issue 1 is caused by the fact that I haven't successfully run 'eb deploy' yet.
```

Any insight would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: It's 3.6, but within the log, python 2.7 is referenced: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
install_dependencies()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)